# After changing form to FormData in Ajax, codeigniter form validation didn't work

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I wrote some code in CodeIgniter3 framework. I wrote a code that shows form validations with Ajax right after input fields. However, I added "upload image" function, for this reason, changed my ajax file from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#continueregistrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    var form = $(this);


$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    processData : false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
    console.log(response);              
        if(response.success) {                  
            $("#messages").html(response.messages);
            $("#continueregistrationform")[0].reset();
            $(".text-danger").remove();
            $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
            location.href = "http://localhost/edu-center/";

        }
        else {
            $("#messages").html(response.messages);
            $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                var element = $("#"+index);
                $(element).parent('div').find('.text-danger').remove();
                $(element).after(value);

            });
        }
    } // /success
});  // /ajax

return false;
}); 
});
```

to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#continueregistrationform").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#continueregistrationform')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: formData.attr('action'),
    type: formData.attr('method'),
    data: formData,
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType: false,
    processData : false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
    console.log(response);              
        if(response.success) {                  
            location.href = "http://localhost/edu-center/";
        }
        else {
            $("#messages").html(response.messages);
            $.each(response.messages, function(index, value) {
                var element = $("#"+index);
                $(element).parent('div').find('.text-danger').remove();
                $(element).after(value);

            });
        }
    } // /success
});  // /ajax

return false;
}); 
});
```

Now instead of showing errors like before under the input fields, it shows them in a new blank white page.[image] Where can be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally not use formData.attr to set the action and method. You may want to verify that the values of formData.attr('action') and formData.attr('method') are what you expect them to be.

From my own personal experience doing exactly what you're doing, this is how I added the image and post variables to the ajax request:

```
// Add file
var formData = new FormData();
var fileInput = $('#your_image_upload_field')[0];
var file = fileInput.files[0];
formData.append('userfile[]', file); // MUST HAVE [] OR PHP HAS NO $_FILES !!! 
// Add post vars
formData.append('a', a);
formData.append('b', b);
formData.append('c', c);
// Do post
$.ajax({ //...
```

Comment: Seems like you are not even having an AJAX request, but maybe your form is just posting to its action. What happens if you hard code in the url of the AJAX request?

Comment: what means hard code in the url? Actually it updates all columns if there is no validation error